# how to add bitmap image and text into the listview or in hashmap in android

Tags: android

how to add the image that is get from URL and text using image loader in hashmap android.
 i tried whatever in below link

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

Comment: your question is a little vague, do you want a custom listview with an image? also are you using `imageloader` library?